# mysql + sqlalchemy create table auto increment

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

In sqlalchemy, I am trying to create a table with a primary key tenant_id and a different auto increment column tenant_index as below

```
class Tenant(Base):
    """Data Model for tenants table"""

    __tablename__ = "tenants"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": DATABASE}

    tenant_index = Column(
        BigInteger,
        primary_key=True,---->1
        nullable=False,
        autoincrement=True,
    )
    name = Column(String(64), nullable=False)
    prefix = Column(String(32), nullable=True, unique=True)
    tenant_id = Column(String(32), 
        primary_key=True, ---->2
        nullable=False, 
        server_default=""
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Tenant model {self.tenant_id}>"

Table generated
mysql> desc tenants;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| tenant_index | bigint      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name         | varchar(64) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| prefix       | varchar(32) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| tenant_id    | varchar(32) | NO   | PRI |         |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Note: it has 2 primary keys -- is it ok to have 2 primary keys in 1 table ?

If I remove primary_key=true, from tenant_index column, table is getting created as below

```
mysql> desc tenants;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| tenant_index | bigint      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name         | varchar(64) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| prefix       | varchar(32) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| tenant_id    | varchar(32) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

but when i try to add data, its telling no default value -- which means auto increment is not working

```
mysql> insert into tenants (name,prefix,tenant_id) values("naveen1","kumar1","11");
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'tenant_index' doesn't have a default value
```

what am i doing wrong, please help
I need tenant_id as primary key, i need tenant_index as auto-increment

Answer (score 0):

A table cannot have two primary keys, but a single primary key may include two columns. This means you need to define the primary key constraint separately, not as an attribute of either column.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/constraints.html#primary-key-constraint shows an example:

```
my_table = Table(
    "mytable",
    metadata_obj,
    Column("id", Integer),
    Column("version_id", Integer),
    Column("data", String(50)),
    PrimaryKeyConstraint("id", "version_id", name="mytable_pk"),
)
```

---

Edit: I tested some more options and I looked at the SQLAlchemy code. It seems that although MySQL does support any column to be auto-increment as long as the column is the first column in any index (unique or non-unique), SQLAlchemy is more limited. I can't get it to add a column as auto-increment unless it's part of the primary key.

Comment: Yes, i know there cannot be 2 PK in one table, problem is if i remove primary_key=true from tenant_index column then autoincrement is not getting applied.

Comment: Did you keep `autoincrement=True` on the first column?

Comment: yes autoincrement=True was there, same snippet as above, just comment out primary_key=True

Comment: I tested (Python 3.10.8, SQLAlchemy 1.4.44, MySQL Connector/Python 8.0.30), and your example model class works fine. Both columns have the primary_key property. SQLAlchemy outputs table DDL with a PK constraint with two columns, the first column is auto-increment. What versions are you using?

Comment: Yes, what i posted above is working fine....it created a composite primary key on two columns tenant_id and tenant_index....even auto increment is working fine.....i tested that too.....my only doubt  when posting the question was if there is a way to create a auto increment column without specifying it as primary key via sqlalchemy. In mysql i have alter command as below...
````
alter table tenants add column new_tenant_id bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ADD key (new_tenant_id);
````
But couldn't get how to write in sqlalchemy

Comment: As PK is changing from single column tenant_id to multi column [tenant_id + tenant_index], other table creation is failing in which tenant_id is a foreign key
````
Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'tenant_settings_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'tenants'")
````
Is there a way to create a column with autoincrement without specifying it as Primary key......any other key is ok with me like unique key or some index etc